# Is anyone aware of a mini refrigerator model with a flat bottom for use as fermentation chamber?

Tags: fermentation, fermentation-temperature, temperature, first-time-brewer, temperature-control

Searching like crazy to find a mini refrigerator with a flat bottom. Any model will work, as I am new to this and only brewing 1 gallon batches. Ideally it would hold a 5gal carboy so that I do not need to shop for one again when I progress to larger batches in the future. Trying to prevent building a custom fermentation chamber until I progress.

Every one I find seems to have the shelf on the bottom.

Thanks and happy brewing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a wine fridge that I took the shelves out of. I can fit a 5 gallon fermenter into it. It has a digital temp display on the front and I set that to the temp I want, it works well for the German lagers I make. Most wne fridges I looked at when I was after one had a flat bottom big enough to take a 5 gallon fermenter.

Comment: This is a great idea, gonna do a little homework on this but it sounds like the solution I've been wanting.

Answer (score 1):

A keggarator is a good choice, if it's not in use for serving. I have an old BevAir it fits two 6g Itialian carboys nicely.

If you have a good back, deep freezers work nice too.

As far as a flat bottom fridge, all of them I've seen converted usually have a DIY second bottom to make it level.

Whatever you choose you will need to add a digital temp controller to.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think I am going to have to make the second bottom. Was really hoping to find a mini fridge to hold the 5gal carboy both for saving space and not having to test my carpentry skills. I already have the stc-1000 rigged up to regulate hot and cold so thats a plus. If i have to build the second bottom I may as well build it big enough for 2 carboys. :)